# check particular time greater than or equal to other time range in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, timespan

I have one varibale endtime which I have declared like this:

```
 Dim endtime As TimeSpan.
```

I am getting some time to this variable. 
example(10:00:01).
I want to check my endtime is greater than or equal to 12,clock 
so I try to given code like this:

```
  if(endtime>=12)
```

But it is showing error like this:

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible > can be called with
>   this argument and value type integer cannot be converted to
>   `system.timespan`.

How I can compare my endtime value to other time? If any one know please help me.

Comment: What the wrong i did??? while doing program i got one error. that i just posted to this sit.That s all

Comment: Well this site is not LearnVbIn21Days.SE.  This site is for `professionals and enthusiasts` (see FAQ).  A person that can not figure out how to compare two variables is neither a professional nor an enthusiast.  They are a rank novice (not a bad thing, we all start there).  There are more appropriate sites for them to be asking their questions.  Sites (and books, and classes) geared specifically to learning a chosen language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply create another TimeSpan variable with the desired value and then you could compare the two variables

```
Dim t2 = new TimeSpan(10,0,1)
Dim t1 = new TimeSpan(12,0,0)
if t1 > t2 then
    Console.WriteLine("T2 greater than T1")
Else
    Console.WriteLine("T1 greater than T2")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of coding

```
endtime>= #12:00:00 PM#
```

Or browse to the link below

> [Browse Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603182/how-can-i-compare-two-times-in-vb-net)