# Comparing time in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How can I compare two diferent Time object in VB.Net. I have implemented the following snippet. I am still unable to get the desired output.

```
time_One = Now
el_Time = time_One - time_Two
Label1.Text = Now.ToShortTimeString
If Label1.Text < "06:30:00 PM" Then
Label1.Text = "-----"
Else
Label1.Text = el_Time.ToString
End If
```

---

Test Case:

I want to compare the current time with "`06:30:00 PM`".

If the current time is smaller than "`06:30:00 PM`" then, perform an action

Comment: Do you really think working with these values as *text* will be easier than using the built in comparison operations that the `DateTime` class has?

Comment: possible dublicate 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603182/how-can-i-compare-two-times-in-vb-net?rq=1)

Comment: Only run this code after lunch.  You don't want to compare "10:00:00 AM".  Get ahead by using a variable instead of the label's Text property.

Answer (score 1):

Declare **time_One, time_Two and  el_Time** as **date datatype**.

Then do the time comparison as:

```
 time_One = Now
 el_Time = New Date(DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, time_One, time_Two)

 If DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, TimeValue(Label1.Text), TimeValue("06:30 PM")) < 0 Then
    Label1.Text = "-----"
 Else
    Label1.Text = el_Time.ToString
 End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this simple way:

```
Dim dtNow As Date = Date.Now()
Dim myDate As Date = New Date(dtNow.Year, dtNow.Month, dtNow.Day, 6, 30, 0)

If myDate < dtNow Then
    ' Perform an action
End If
```

It uses the Date constructor to create a new DateTime with the same day as today and the desired time, to compare it with the actual time and date. Then uses the comparing operator given by Date type.

Answer (score 0):

You could use TimeSpan. Take a look at this:

```
Dim dtLimit As New TimeSpan(6, 30, 0)
Dim iMinutes As Double = (Date.Now.TimeOfDay - dtLimit).TotalMinutes 

If iMinutes < 0 Then 
    ' Perform an action
End If
```

This code calculates the difference between two given moments (only time, without date); the present one and the desired one.